# What does "under me" mean in this passage?

Tags: meaning, prepositions

Could you tell me what "under me" means in the following passage?

> "And does Mr. Rackstraw look after that [=occult stuff] too?" asked Colquhoun.
> "Well, some of it," the publisher answered. "But of course, in a place like this things aren't exactly divided just--just exactly. Mornington, now, Mornington looks after some books. Under me, of course," he added hastily. "And then he does a good deal of the publicity, the advertisements, you know. And he does the reviews."
>
> (Charles Williams, *War in Heaven*)

Does it mean "under my supervision"? But it doesn't seem to make much sense to me.

Comment: The speaker is Mornington's boss - he doesn't necessarily supervise Mornington's work closely, but he probably has to approve the books before they are published.

Answer (score 1):

[under](https://www.lexico.com/definition/under): "controlled, managed or governed by." [Lexico]

It means the publisher is ultimately responsible for what Mornington does. Control and management can be [arm's length](https://www.lexico.com/definition/arm%27s-length) rather than close control, and the publisher might simply keep a [watching brief](https://www.lexico.com/definition/watching_brief)  to make sure things are done the way the publishing house should do them. The context does indicate that Mornington has considerable responsibility, but the publisher is anxious to indicate that *he* isn't completely superfluous.